# Validation on textfield

Tags: 7, forms

I have gotten my validation module to kind of work, I have this:

function product_id_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {

```
if($form_state['node']->field_product_id['und']['0']['value'] == '123'){
    form_set_error('field_product_id', 'Product ID: is taken');
}
```

}

But when I change the value in field_product_id the value doesn't change upon save, it stays the same as when I first entered the form. Is there a function I need to call to say, when I click save look at this field again?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Submitted values are stored in the `$form_state['values']` array so you need to test that instead:

```
if ($form_state['values']['field_product_id'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] == '123') {
  ...
}
```